# Symfony: Load Security Users from the Database

Tags: php, symfony

I read the official documentation of Symfony in order to give access to a specific page. I followed the instructions, but when I insert user and pw the I am not redirected to protected page.

This is the entity

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="users")
*/
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
 */
private $isActive;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->isActive = true;
    // may not be needed, see section on salt below
    // $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
}

public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->username;
}

public function getSalt()
{
    // you *may* need a real salt depending on your encoder
    // see section on salt below
    return null;
}

public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

public function getRoles()
{
    return array('ROLE_ADMIN');
}

public function eraseCredentials()
{
}

/** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(array(
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password,
        // see section on salt below
        // $this->salt,
    ));
}

/** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    list (
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password,
        // see section on salt below
        // $this->salt
    ) = unserialize($serialized);
   }
```

This is the security.yml

```
security:
encoders:
    AppBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt


role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_ADMIN
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

providers:
    our_db_provider:
        entity:
            class: AppBundle:User
            property: username

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt|error)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        http_basic: ~

    default:
       pattern:    ^/
       http_basic: ~
       provider: our_db_provider

access_control:
    - { path: ^/dashboard/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

The password has been inserted manually in the database using this BCrypt [tool](https://www.dailycred.com/article/bcrypt-calculator)

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: So, does authentication or authorization fails? Can you update your question with log recorded during the login?

Comment: Hi, the authentication is failing. I am new to Symfony and I don't know where to find the log recorded

Comment: Start by looking into `app/logs/dev.log` (assuming you are running from `app_dev.php`)

Comment: Hi, I found this:[Mon Jul 13 12:43:24.223213 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 63398] [client ::1:65323] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/newApp/app/logs/dev.log

Comment: I found the error. I did not include the Entity/User in the controller

Answer (score 0):

I am not a specialist, but I think you forget to specify some stuff in your security file in the firewalls definition. You can find mine below.

```
form_login:
            login_path: fos_user_security_login
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
            default_target_path: route to your logged user should go after logged
        logout:
            path: fos_user_security_logout
            target: route to your user should go after logout
```